# Saving data to database using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm creating a browser RPG game. I want to allow a user to save their current stats by updating the mysql db without having to reload the page... So I thought jquery could help.

The user will not be adding their own stats. The stats are generated through user actions, such as solving a challenge. I want the user to be able to save those updated stats to the database whenever they would like.

The issues are:

- the jQuery is outputting the `echo "saved..." . $stats . ", " . $stats2;` before I click the Save button.
- When I click save, the database field isn't being updated.

I'm wondering why this isn't working. When I click save, the stats fields shouldn't be `0`, but should be the stats that are shown- `11`. The database fields should also be updated.

For testing purposes, I've just created js variable `var stats` that is updated when the arrow keys are pressed.

I call the function updateHUD() to do `$('#stats').html(stats);` which updates the HTML.

```
function updateHUD() {  
    $('#stats').html(stats);
}
```

Then updateHUD is called after arrow key is pressed.

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="span12">
    <button onclick="saveData(stats)" name="input" value="">Save Data</button>
        <br /><span id="output"></span><br />
        <ul>
        <li><b>Stats 1:</b>     <span id="stats"></span>    </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
//Pass saved data to store in DB
$(document).ready(function() {
    saveData();
});


function saveData() {     
   $.get("php/CRUD.php", {"_input" : $('input[name=input]').val()},
        function(returned_data) {
            $("#output").html(returned_data);
        }
    );
}
```

---

**PHP**

```
<?php
//store all player data in array and save to/update db
include 'DbConnect.php';
session_start();

$stats = (isset($_GET['_input']) ? ($_GET['_input']) : 0); 

$formvars = array();
array_push($formvars, $stats);      

echo $stats;
echo $_SESSION['username'];


$qry = 'UPDATE users SET stats="'.$stats.'" WHERE username="' . $_SESSION['username'] . '"';    
$mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

echo "saved..." . $stats;
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

---

**Output**

```
saved...0 //this should be 11
Stats 1: 11
```

Comment: Make var_dump($_GET); and post at comment

Comment: It is outputting it before because you are calling `saveData` on doucment ready.

Comment: I am not sure but if you want to show updated data from db then there must be select query to fetch data from db and show latest status

Comment: You are trying to get `$('input[name=input]').val()`, but there is no `input` at all in your markup.

Comment: @epascarello okay I've removed document ready which fixes the values being displayed before I click the button, but the stats still aren't being updated in the db nor are they being returned correctly from the jQuery

Comment: @moonwave99 the button onclick name is `input`

Comment: Where / how in the javascript is the stats value stored?

Comment: @Growler yeah, but that's a `button`, not an `input` ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do a

`$('input[name=input]').val()`

but you have named the submit button "input" instead of adding a input box with this name.

But the question is unclear anyways.

You want to give a user the permission to  update his stat with the value that he wants? You should update the question to make it more clear since it does not make much sense at the moment.

Comment: How do I fix this for my case? And no, I don't want the user to update with the value he wants. The stats are generated automatically

Comment: I just edited my answer. Pls update your question, what exactly you want to do. It is unclear.

Comment: Where are the stats are stored? There is nothing in the code you posted. Are they in a variable? In a hidden input? Where are they?

Comment: I assume you want to pull the data from the <span> element with id "stats", no?

Comment: so,  $('#stats').html() ?

Comment: But the span element does also have no value assigned.

Comment: No, but I assume it should have. I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Hecksa Yes. For testing purposes, I've just created two js variables `var stats and var stats2` that are updated when the arrow keys are pressed. I call a function `updateHUD()` to do `$('#stats').html(stats);` which updates the HTML. (For now I don't care about stats2 var, just want stats to work first)

Comment: @Growler: Pleas eupdate the wquestion with all the informations and the new code. We want to help you but we don't want to guess what you actually want.

Comment: @Michael I've updated the question. Hope it's clearer

Comment: Do you actually understand javascript/jquery? Now you try to get a value from non existing fields.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the original answer is basically right here - you just need to replace $('input[name=input]').val() with $('#stats').html() in the AJAX call. Like Michael says though, it's hard to tell exactly what data you want to be sent where.

Comment: The code is weird anyways. Now you update the stats element when the user presses a arrow key. What if the user submits it without pressing the arrow key? I really have to think that you are not that familar with Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: @Michael - in fairness, the asker's competence with Jquery is irrelevant - there's no "question difficulty" requirement on SO, just quality/clarity requirements. Admittedly, the question could be clearer, but I've seen many worse.

Comment: I was just testing a jQuery update to the database. If the user submits it without pressing the arrow key, then all they would be doing is submitting their current stat of `0` to the database. The arrow key just acts as an updater for the stats for now. That's all. And I'm not familiar with jQuery, I'm learning, which is the point of my project.

Comment: @Hecksa: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. " Currently it looks like he is trying many thing without actually understanding them ;)

Comment: `$.get("php/CRUD.php", {"_input" : $('#stats').html()},` doesn't work, no

Comment: `$.post`? You have `$.get` in your above code. Sorry i won't try to help you with this anymore since you make it very complicated. Please consider to take a look at the jquery docs to learn how the functions you use work.

Comment: I expected that, i wondered why it should still not work. Glad we were able to resolve that.

Comment: @Michael sorry for the lack of clarity. I need to work on how I ask questions. lol

Comment: Yeah it would make it easier to get a working solution within some mins :P Have a nice day :)

Comment: Glad we got there in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try using `load`:

```
//Pass saved data to store in DB
$(document).ready(function() {
    saveData();
});


$.fn.saveData=function(){
   $('#divforload').css('display','none');
   $('#divforload').load("php/CRUD.php?stats="+$('#stats').val(),function(){$('#divforload').fadeIn();});
}
//Just call the function onClick...
//Need an input called 'stats'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First your selector where you are getting your data from is incorrect.** You need to either change your html...

```
<button name="input"></button>
```

to an...

```
<input type="button" name="input" />
```

or change your jQuery selector...

```
$('input[name=input]')
```

to select the correct element

```
$('button[name=input]')
```

**Second you need to make sure your button's 'value=""' actually has data in it when the ajax function is being called.**

```
<button onclick="saveData(stats)" name="input" value="[Data Value Goes Here]">Save Data</button>
```

**Finally the reason your jQuery is outputting before you click the the save button is because you are executing the function as soon as the document loads.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    saveData();
});
```

*Try something more like this:*

**HTML**

```
<button name="input" value="[data goes here]">Save Data</button>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
//Pass saved data to store in DB
$('button[name=input]').on('click', saveData);


function saveData() {     
    $.get("php/CRUD.php", {"_input" : $(this).val()},
        function(returned_data) {
            $("#output").html(returned_data);
        }
    );
}
```